# How to design a function that takes array of function pointers as an argument in C++?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am trying to define a `ScalarField` class, an abstraction of a scalar (for example, temperature) in 3D. The member array, `scalar_` (`sizeof(scalar_) = N`), of this class is the linear representation of scalar in 3D. There are `n` (`n < N`) nonidentical sources of this scalar in space, though sparse, i.e. sources are only present at select positions, (i, j, k), in the space. Each of these `n` nonidentical sources are a function of the scalar value at the source location.

I have defined `n` functions for sources as  shown below. I would like to implement a member function, `GetSource`, inside `ScalarField` that computes the magnitude of source at a given location, (i, j, k), if one exists, in this 3D space. Since the sources are nonidentical, I was thinking of using function pointers. Below is how I was trying to implement the class.

```
// Source functions
double Source_1(double scalar) {
  // compute the source value
}
.
.
.
double Source_n(double scalar) {
  // compute the source value
}

// Scalar field class
class ScalarField {
  public:
    // constructors
    // destructor

    // Get the linear index
    size_t CartesianToLinear(const size_t i, const size_t j, const size_t k) {
      // increment along x, followed by y, followed by z
      return i + dim_x_ * j + dim_x_ * dim_y_ * k;
    }
    // Get the scalar value at position (i, j, k)
    double operator()(const size_t i, const size_t j, const size_t k) const {
      return scalar_[CartesianToLinear(i, j, k)];
    }
    // Compute the source magnitude at (i, j, k)
    double GetSource(const size_t i, const size_t j, const size_t k, 
                         double (*SourceFunc) (double)) {
      return SourceFunc((*this)(i, j, k));
    }

  private:
  std::vector<double> scalar_{};
  size_t dim_x_, dim_y_, dim_z_; // domain size along, x, y, z
};
```

The trouble I have is with passing the function pointer to `GetSource`. What would be a good design to pass different source functions based on the position in 3D space?

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve. Do you want to pass several function pointers? Do you want to avoid function pointers? What kinds of functions do you want to pass?

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are asking, which isnt really clear. is it the case that you want the class ScalarField to contain n source/sinks but you dont know how to do that since each source/sink is associated with a different function?

Comment: It sounds like it would be a lot more straightforward to pass the field to the source/sink rather than the other way around. That is, unless the source/sink are meant to mutate the field in a way that is not being shown in the question.

Comment: Consider passing a structure containing function pointers.  The struct allows for different function pointers.  Arrays and vectors require the function pointers to have the same type.

Comment: @n314159, I tried to rephrase the question. Hope it is better phrased and clear.

Comment: @jwezorek, yes, I want the `ScalarField` to be associated with `n` different, nonidentical sources, with each source associated with a different function.

Comment: How do you know which SourceFunc should be used for certain ranges of 3d space?  I'm expecting you don't want to have to configure a SourceFunc for each and every 3d point (which would be easy to code) but rather have certain SourceFunc for different regions of 3d space.  If the regions are always cuboid it would be pretty easy but then what do you do with overlapping regions?

Comment: What is the problem here, seems like it's working fine?

Comment: @Ranoiaetep The question at the end is `What would be a good design to pass different source functions based on the position in 3D space?` so I think that means he doesn't want to pass a function but rather a data structure containing a bunch of functions - one of which gets chosen based on the i, j, and k passwd in..

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, I would have to define a sparse array of indices for source location and I would have certain SourceFunc for different regions of 3D space.  The regions are always cuboid and non-overlapping.